# Проблемы с интернетом

Tags: многопоточность, wifi, lan, ethernet

Использую множество программ парсеров примерно все вместе используют 2000 потоков.
Проблема в том что я хотел увеличить колл-во потоков (железо позволяет)
и столкнулся с проблемой что софты начинают лагать и работают даже медленнее чем обычно. Компьютер подключен через гбит роутер (брал не дорогой) и от роутера идет в свитч и от свича к 2м компам.
Я думаю проблема в роутере но не уверен в этом. Смотрел нагрузку на сеть в мониторинге она не большая гбит должен ее с легкостью обрабатывать.
Модель роутера D-link DIR 825 AC1200 Dual Band Gigabit
Модель свича tp-link TL-SG1008D.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
Поможет ли замена роутера на более производительны? если да то подскажите модель хорошего роутера.

Comment: Вы ограничены самым узким каналом. Вряд ли в роутер приходит 1 Гб/с от провайдера.

Comment: Ну по тесту 600 мб.с
Но суть даже не в этом нагрузка на сеть не более 10 мегабайт по мониторингу запас еще есть. Может быть такое что роутер или свитч не успевает обрабатывать потоки так быстро?